Adb команды , разрешения adb
Ребят, такой вопрос , у меня китайский автомобиль ПИ, приложения установлены , но работают через лаунчер.
Головное устройство в машине не показывает (иконки) на экране.
Вопрос: существует ли команда adb позволяющая дать разрешение на то, чтоб иконки отображались. Понимаю так , что ГУ показывает только те приложения, которые находятся в белом списке... Остальные просто не отображает.
Спасибо!
